# Build Lollipop 5.1.1 Aosp on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: android-source, ubuntu-18.04, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am getting below error while trying to build Lollipop 5.1.1 AOSP on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
build/core/Makefile:34: warning: overriding recipe for target 'out/target/product/apq8084/system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector.xml'
build/core/base_rules.mk:550: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'out/target/product/apq8084/system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector.xml'
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE apq8084
Lex: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l
/bin/bash: prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39: Is a directory
build/core/binary.mk:575: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp] Error 126
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
host C++: libaapt_32 <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptXml.cpp
make: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.

#### make failed to build some targets (01:06 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Any Idea why this happens?

I tried "export LC_ALL=C" but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebuild the flex package and the issue got resolved.

cd prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex

rm flex-2.5.39
   tar zvxf flex-2.5.39.tar.gz
   cd flex-2.5.39

./configure
   make

mv flex ../
   cd ../

rm -rf flex-2.5.39
   mv flex flex-2.5.39